Rendering CSS Objects in Flutter App from Admin Website Data
I'm developing a Flutter app where data is fetched from an admin website, including UI configurations that utilize CSS-like objects. The admin website sends UI configurations in JSON format, where styles for elements like titles and menus are defined using CSS properties. Here's an example of the JSON structure:
"titleStyles": {
    "color": "#A94E2F",
    "fontSize": 30,
    "fontWeight": "bold"
},
"menuStyles": {
    "display": "flex",
    "justify-content": "space-between"
},

I need to dynamically render these styles in my Flutter app, ensuring compatibility with various CSS properties that may be included.
Questions:

How can I parse and apply CSS-like objects from JSON data in Flutter for styling UI components?

What strategies or libraries can I use to handle and render these CSS properties effectively in my Flutter widgets?

Are there any best practices or recommended approaches for integrating external UI configurations, including CSS styles, into a Flutter application?


Any guidance or examples demonstrating how to implement this would be greatly appreciated!
Updates: I checked out flutter-view library to solve my problem but it's last version 2 years ago. And also it doesn't support Dart 3.
I also found this website, but I can't use it as library.
I am still looking for solution for my problem. I would be appreciated if someone helps me about that.

You can not handle all the CSS properties. Either use some agreed upon properties or use a Web Page.
